# why is my code not removing internal rectangle

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, cython

please check this code as algorithm told by @Arun R in [how to find area of rectangle which is covering another rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23656987/how-to-find-area-of-rectangle-which-is-covering-another-rectangle/23701028#) what is wrong in it

my output is
[image]

why is it not removing the rectangle inside other

```
cdef class Ray:
    cdef public:
        Point2D p
        Point2D q
        list points

cdef class Boundbox:
    cdef public:
        Point2D minP
        Point2D maxP
        int componentID

        int getComponentID(self):
            return self.componentID
def __numeric_compare_by_x(self,Boundbox a,Boundbox b):
    cdef Point2D tempA,tempB
    tempA=a.minP
    tempB=b.minP
    return tempA.x-tempB.x

def __numeric_compare_by_y(self,Boundbox a,Boundbox b):
    cdef Point2D tempA,tempB
    tempA=a.minP
    tempB=b.minP
    return tempA.y-tempB.y

def isBoundbox_inside(self,b1,b2):
    if((b1.minP.x<=b2.minP.x and b1.minP.y<=b2.minP.y)and(b1.maxP.x>=b2.maxP.x and b1.maxP.y>=b2.maxP.y)):
        return True
    return False

def boundboxFilter(self,boundbox):

    cdef:
        int i
        int minx,miny,maxx,maxy
        list pointList=[]
        Boundbox p,b1,b2

    #for i in xrange(len(boundbox)):
    #    pointList.append(boundbox[i])

    pointList=boundbox
    pointList.sort(cmp=self.__numeric_compare_by_x)

    stack=[]
    stack.append(pointList[0])

    for p in pointList[1:]:
        top=len(stack)-1
        b1=stack[top]
        b2=p
        if(not(self.isBoundbox_inside(b1,b2))):
            stack.append(b2)

    pointList=stack
    pointList.sort(cmp=self.__numeric_compare_by_y)

    stack=[]
    stack.append(pointList[0])
    for p in pointList[1:]:
        top=len(stack)-1
        b1=stack[top]
        b2=p
        if(not(self.isBoundbox_inside(b1,b2))):
            stack.append(b2)

    return stack
```

Comment: can you show a simpler example, maybe exactly two rectangles, the containing and the one to be removed? it's quite hard to understand what's going on with such a complex input

Comment: my input is list of [minx,miny,maxx,maxy] of all rectangle as shown in image

Comment: Maybe you could try to tweak [the hierarchy functionality](http://opencvpython.blogspot.ch/2013/01/contours-5-hierarchy.html) in OpenCV instead of using a custom algorithm?

Comment: I don't mean a parameter list, but concrete input values and expected output values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your filtering logic.

```
outsiders = []
for rect in pointList:
    if not any(is_inside(rect, box) for box in pointlist if box is not rect):
        outsiders.append(rect)
```

Where `is_inside` is true if `rect` is inside `box`. You need to check each rectangle against all the others, and save it if it is not inside any of them. You can of course tweak it for performance.

Another way that will require less comparisons is to consider the whole list, and remove the rectangles that are found inside others. But then you would have to be very careful with the indexing, and popping things in the middle of a list is expensive too.

Comment: is there any efficient way to do this job

Comment: @Rahol from previous comment could be better option